# can you use react server to forward your request to backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, frontend, backend

I am working on a tool where frontend is made with react js (create-react-app and served with [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve))  and backend is made with express+node and both of the servers are running on different Docker container on a remote machine. now the problem is sys admin is saying he will only make frontend accessible from outside the world and backend container is only accessible by frontend container. Since I am making calls XMLHttpRequest on /API/example and backend does not have public URL so can I use frontend server to redirect my request to the backend?

To make my self clear this is what I want to do, frontend is running on `https://frontend.com` and I make API/example call from browser to `https://frontend.com/API/example` and server will redirect this call to backend and reply back with a response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use some sort of webserver instead of [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) npm package. The problem in your case is that you want to proxy all requests to backend and serve package is only a static server. The easiest method for you is to write a custom node js script, serve the static assets (e.g. with [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express)) and proxy all requests to backend. (e.g. with [express-http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy)).

A sample code would look like this:

```
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
const app = require('express')();  
app.use('/api', proxy('http://backend.url')); // this will proxy all incoming requests to /api route to backend base url
app.use(express.static(‘path/to/your/static/assets’)); // these were previously served with serve
app.listen(3000, () => console.log(‘Frontend listening on port: 3000’));
```

Another possible way is to use nginx, apache or whatever webserver you’d like and do essentially the same.